# assign json array (id's) with mysql tables PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a json array in mysql table called "feature_ids":

`{"20":"38","38":"328","22":"106","23":"129","131":"2500"}`

where key:value is an "id" from "features" table. features table look's like this:

`id|name
20|feat1
38|feat2`

How can i get in php/smarty "name" from "features" table instead "id's" (i want result like this):

`{"feat1":"feat2","feat3":"feat4"}`

Comment: In the result string don't you want the values too?

Comment: If you need joining tables based on what's in the json field, then you should not use a json field, you should normalise your data.